# ChartJS on small screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chart.js

I want to make a responsive chart using ChartJS library. Everything works okay on screens wider than ~430px, but under this amount, the chart becomes so small it dissapears. I want to make the graph visible as in 3rd image

More than ~430px:

[image]

Less than ~430px:

[image]

How would I want it:

[image]

EDIT: How currently it looks like:

[image]

```
<div className="graph">
<Topic />
<Doughnut data={{
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
  datasets: [{
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.3)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.3)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.3)',
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
}}
/>
```

That's my code, just copy-paste to test the library. Maybe default height and width would help, but I need it responsive.  How can I set it to work?

CSS wrappers look like this:

```
.Statistics .graphContainer{
   background-color: black;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   border: black solid;
   border-width: 3px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-top: 75px;
   padding: 10px;
}

.Statistics .graph{
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Additionally,  `.graph` lies in `.graphContainer`

Comment: You can set a default width & height when your screen is small than 430px.

Comment: There are [responsive](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) `options` (prop) that can be passed to components such as `<Doughnut />` to make them responsive. Have you tried that option?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It seems that `responsive` option is default, and because it indeed resizes, it's true already

Comment: @dsantoro I tried this on `canvas` and it stretches the graph making it ugly.

Comment: @SlawekWozniak you probably will want to update your question to indicate what you actually want it to look like at mobile screen sizes. This will help ensure you get the best assistance.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky You are right, I just added an image

Comment: did u ever find out how to solve this? i'm having the exact same issue: when my legend is big, the donut graph will vanish.

Comment: You may accept the answer if it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that following settings will work for you. Set responsive to true, maintainAspectRatio to false in the chart options and set style as like as max-height: 300px; width: auto;

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old - but this worked for me

```js
plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: function () {
                    //you can return position based on inner width of your display area
                    if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
                        return "bottom";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving it a `min-width` (something like 200px) and `height: auto`.

Comment: I works, but now div is quite distorted and graph goes out of it

Comment: You could maybe try to change height to `height: fit-content`. If that doesn't work, maybe try using `max-height` with `width: auto`?

Comment: Ok, we're almost there. The second option works and the graph no longer dissapears. But it still looks too small  on mobile devices, can I manipulate the size of it?

Comment: Maybe try giving it `max-height` and `width: 100%`. If that doesn't work either, then I think it has to do with the thing wrapping your graph. Could you share the css for your `graph` className?

Comment: It changed little. I added the css, please take a look on it

Comment: Can your update the screenshots so I can see what your chart looks like on small screen?

Comment: Try giving your graphContainer a `min-height` or `height: 100%`

Comment: No effect at all :/

Comment: I found two things: 1. When I set `min-width` of  `.graph` it has the perfect size, but as I said goes out of the wrapper. It looks as though this graph had some big padding on left. 2. When I turned off legend, the graph got bigger in acceptable way, but still legend is what I'd like to have

Comment: Try removing the legend from the pre-built component and implementing your own version of the legend. This way the graph can be the proper size and you can guarantee that the legend isn't affecting the graph